# Autotools: differences in $VAR, $(VAR) and ${VAR} and ${CC-cc} vs. ${CC}

Tags: autotools

I see both $CFLAGS and ${CFLAGS} being used, configure.ac uses the $CFLAGS and acinclude.m4 uses the ${CFLAGS}. So variables are accessed differently: $VAR, $(VAR) and/or ${VAR}.

I believe $(VAR) and ${VAR} are the same things, and this really depends on preference. But what about $VAR vs. $(VAR)/${VAR}, what's the difference between using brackets or not?

Also with this piece of code: ${CC-cc}, when I display the contents of the variable, I get "gcc". If I take out the "-cc" and just display the contents of ${CC}, I still get "gcc".

So what does the hyphen actually do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see both $CFLAGS and ${CFLAGS} being used, configure.ac uses the
>   $CFLAGS and acinclude.m4 uses the ${CFLAGS}. So variables are accessed
>   differently: $VAR, $(VAR) and/or ${VAR}.

Yes and no.

`configure.ac`, `acinclude.m4`, and other M4 sources that go into building the `configure` script contain a mix of shell code and Autoconf macros, with a little bit of M4 syntax sprinkled in.  Both the shell and M4 use the `$` character to introduce variable references, but what you're seeing is probably mostly shell variable references.  To the shell, `$VAR` as a complete syntactic unit means the same thing as `${VAR}`; both perform "[parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)".  The braces are useful for setting off the variable name from its context, such as in `${VAR}foo`, to indcate that the variable name is `VAR`, not `VARfoo`.  Additionally, the braces are required when certain special parameter expansion features are utilized.

> I believe $(VAR) and ${VAR} are the same things, and this really
>   depends on preference. But what about $VAR vs. $(VAR)/${VAR}, what's
>   the difference between using brackets or not?

It depends on context.  `$(VAR)` means something completely different to the shell than `${VAR}` does: it expands to the output, if any, obtained by running the (literal) command `VAR`.  You will not see it used interchangeably with `${VAR}` in Autoconf code.  But you might see it in `Makefile`s and Automake `Makefile.am` files.  This is because `make` uses [different variable expansion rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference) than the shell does.  To it, `$(VAR)` and `${VAR}` do mean the same thing -- they expand to the value of variable `VAR` -- but `$VAR` means something quite different (and is probably a mistake).  The form with parentheses is more traditional, but the one with curly braces is now widely used, too.

> Also with this piece of code: ${CC-cc}, when I display the contents of
>   the variable, I get "gcc". If I take out the "-cc" and just display
>   the contents of ${CC}, I still get "gcc".
>
> So what does the hyphen actually do here?

This is one of the special features of shell parameter expansion syntax (so it applies to Autoconf code, but not Automake code): `${CC-cc}` expands to the value of variable `CC`, the same as `${CC}`, *provided that `CC` is set*, but if `CC` is not set then `${CC-cc}` expands to the literal text `cc`.

Comment: I searched up shell parameter expansion and came across this article: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html. So I might or might not see the expansion with the colon. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok. Here's what the document says "Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence."

Comment: I think you've got it, @supmethods.